# Laravel 5.5 DetectLostConnection trait not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I just uploaded my Laravel 5.5 project to shared hosting and it works for the front page. But when it comes for the Login and Register part, there comes an error saying

> Trait 'Illuminate\Database\DetectsLostConnections' not found.

What had gone wrong here? Has anyone gone through this issue before?

Comment: Does the file `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/DetectsLostConnections.php` exist inside your shared hosting environment?

Comment: Does your host allow .htaccess to over write configurations.

Comment: Thanks for your response @LeonVismer, the file DetectLostConnection.php does exists on the hosting server, but i just realized the size of the file is 0kb. I re-uploaded everything back and do a little fixing for some bugs and now everything working fine.